# Only some lines throwing "Object variable or with variable not set" error when using .Find method

Tags: vba, excel

(I know this sounds like a repeat question, but I've searched everywhere for this, and I couldn't find anything about this)

I'm trying to automate a tax filing process at work. Essentially, I'm reading off several worksheets and populating relevant fields into a master mapping sheet. However (and this is the strange part), when I first coded everything out, there were no errors and I managed to find everything. After saving and reopening the workbook though, I keep getting this error and only for certain lines (9 occurences out of the 57 times I call the .find method in total).

I know the error means that the .find method couldn't find what I was looking for, but I know the field exists since it worked perfectly well before I closed and reopened the workbook, and it works for the rest of the searches. Does anyone have any ideas?

I've checked my macro security settings (everything is enabled), and I know the .find method isn't retrieving anything (I put in "if ___ is nothing" statements to verify, and the affected lines all return nothing when called), but I know the fields I'm searching for exist in their respective sheets.

Here's one of the lines throwing the error:

```
Range("C7").Select
Set currentRowReference = Worksheets("Stat A").Range("B1:B999").Find("Current year tax losses", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
firstCalculation = Worksheets("Stat A").Cells(currentRowReference.Row - 2, "E")
Set currentRowReference = Worksheets("Stat A").Range("A1:A999").Find("Unabsorbed capital allowances c/f", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
secondCalculation = Worksheets("Stat A").Cells(currentRowReference.Row - 1, "E")
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = firstCalculation - secondCalculation
```

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated!

*Edit: I've added a larger portion of my code, and a screenshot of the sheet it's supposed to read from. In the code above, firstCalculation successfully computes, while secondCalculation throws the error.*

[Screenshot of source sheet. Specifically, it's supposed to read A31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwbJ0.png)

Comment: can you post the rest of your code (relevant section) ? Try to add a screenshot of your sheet, where some cells with the `.Find` criteria can be found.

Comment: Okay sure, done. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @user3598756 the calculation of "secondCalculation" throws the error, meaning that the 2nd time I call the .find statement returns nothing.

Comment: @user3598756 Okay sure, I've removed the part of my comment addressing that as well. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to check if currentRowReference is nothing, i.e. is it found.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes I did in my actual code, and nothing was found. But that's the issue - the field exists in the source sheet, and the code worked the first time I did it. The error started only when I reopened the workbook, and only for some fields (in this case, firstCalculation works and secondCalculation doesn't, although they're both calling the .find method on the same sheet

Comment: Are you sure that "Unabsorbed capital allowances c/f" is actually in column "A"? Since text justification in conjunction with spaces could show it like it were in a cell where it actually is not!

Comment: @user3598756 yes, in the source sheet, cell A31 and B31 are merged

Comment: @user3598756 your comment gave me an idea - I just tried unmerging cell A31 and B31, and it works again! When I remerged the cells, it still works too! When I close and relaunch the workbook, the problem comes up again though, until I unmerge the cell again. This is really interesting, I've never had issues calling the first column of a merged cell in VBA to retrieve a value up till now.

Comment: In line with the previous comment, I've found a workaround of sorts - I changed the range of my .find method from A1:A999 to A1:B999, ie I'll now search through both columns. I'm still going to dig deeper to find out what's going on - it's really bizarre that I've been able to call the first column of a merged cell in VBA to retrieve a value, right up till this issue

Comment: if you want to stick to the "right" column, you can use the function like per my answer

Answer (score 0):

since you have to deal with merged cells, you'd better use a function on your own like the following:

```
Function MyRowFind(rng As Range, textToFind As String) As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    MyRowFind = -1
    For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        If InStr(cell.value, textToFind) > 0 Then
            MyRowFind = cell.Row
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

to be used in your main sub as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim currentRowReferenceRow As Long

    currentRowReferenceRow = MyRowFind(Worksheets("Stat A").Range("A1:A999"), "Unabsorbed capital allowances c/f")
    If currentRowReferenceRow > 0 Then
        ' code
    End If
End Sub
```